# How to make Second Wind a non-Standard action?

Tags: dnd-4e, second-wind

[Second Wind](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=334) is a Standard Action that allow you to use a healing surge and get a defensive bonus for one turn.

What are the options the system gives to reduce this action from Standard to anything else?

Comment: This might be answerable if you told us the situation you're facing--the race, class, level, etc, of the character you're using, as well as what limits you're willing to accept (encounter powers and triggered effects are common ways to reduce the action required for Second Wind, but they're limited in frequency and control). As currently phrased, this is far too broad and listy for the Stack's format.

Comment: Do you prefer if I open a question "I have a Dwarf Warden that want to optimize Second Wind"? And then another one for Human Fighter, then for Elf Barbarian, then... Second Wind optimization is a common question for 4e, so I think it is a valid question. It's not open-ended, and it's not opinion-based. And Stack rules are ok with self-answered questions, right?

Comment: Related discussion on meta: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/i-want-to-post-some-questions-that-will-require-finite-community-wiki-list-an

Comment: If you intend this to be a community resource list, that's a *very* different context than if you're asking for an actionable solution to a challenge you're facing. Self-answering doesn't come into it.

Comment: To be fair, I was going to ask this exact question. Then I stopped and looked for the answer myself and compiled the list. I had no idea that listing resources for the community was frowned upon on Stack until Jeffrey put that link there. At the time of my previous comment, the only thing I had some doubt was from self-answering. So, yeah. I stand corrected, and will wait you guys decide if you want to keep the topic around or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to use a Second Wind with a less costly action than Standard.

**Move Action:**

- Ranger Utility [Invigorating Stride](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10606) (MP2)

**Minor Action:**

- [Dwarf](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/race.aspx?id=2) racial power, once per encounter (PHB)
- Fighter Attack [Restoring Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9995), if you hit with it (D379)
- Warden Utility [Soothing Wind](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9848) (PrP)
- Warden Attack [Form of the Frenzied Wolverine](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5127), while the form lasts (PH2)
- [Avatar of Life](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=434) Feature Persistence of Life (DP)
- Feat [Frantic Recovery](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2570), when you use an Action Point (D383)
- *(Daily)* Armor of Dwarven Vigor (AV2)
- *(Daily)* [Standard of Taraskir](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3502), Standard action to activate. You and allies in the zone can use Second Wind as a minor action. (Dungeon 202)

**Free Action:**

- [Glorious Myrmidon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=544) Utility [Exult in Victory](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10570), when you kill an enemy. (MP2)
- [Questing Knight](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=427) Feature Knight's Resurgence, when bloodied (DP)
- Purple Dragon Knight Feature Purple Dragon Focus, when using an Action Point (FRPG)
- [Bear Warrior](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=258) Feature Bear Form, while raging (PH2)
- [Blood Moon Stalker](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=266) Feature Blood Moon Hunger, when you kill an enemy with a melee or close attack. (PH2)
- [Mythic Spirit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=506) Feature Mythic Rebirth, while dying (PrP)
- Feat [Hunter's Resurgence](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=353), when you kill your Quarry (MP)
- Feat [Stoneheart Warrior](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=902) (MP)
- Feat [Timely Revival](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=907), when you succeed in a Death Save (MP)
- Feat [Wild Surge](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1936), when using Wild Shape into humanoid form (PrP)
- *(Daily)* Grandmaster Training [Restful Lullaby](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3516) (D415)
- *(Daily)* Grandmaster Training [Magnificent Tsor's Unrelenting Fury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1790) (D393)

**Triggered Actions:**

- *(Reaction)* [Samurai](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=935) Utility [Honorable Resolve](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=16001), when bloodied (D404)
- *(Free)* [Kulkor Arms Master](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=546) Utility [Tempered in Blood](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10577), when bloodied (MP2)
- *(Interrupt)* [Stonecaller](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=416) Utility [Rooted to the Earth](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=8086), when you or ally is subject to forced movement, target can use Second Wind (DP)
- *(Interrupt)* Feat [Resilience of Stone](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2458), when you are damaged (MP2)
- *(Interrupt)* Feat [Peerless Reaction](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1685), when you are hit (PH3)

**Ally's Actions:**

- *(Standard)* [Heal](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=9) skill, DC 10 (PHB)
- *(Minor)* Heal Utility [Swift Recovery](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9319) (PH3)
- *(Standard)* [Callidyrr Dragoon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/Theme.aspx?id=940) Level 10 Feature: Can use Diplomacy as if it were Heal to grant a use of second wind. (D405)
- *(Minor)* Warlord Utility [Encouraging Boost](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10916) (MP2)
- *(Minor)* Wizard Utility [Herbal Healing](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=14547) (HotF)
- *(Standard)* Warlord Attack [Surging Assault](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=11609), all allies adjacent (D384)
- *(Minor)* Warlord Utility [Bolstering Shout](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4573), for one turn, allies can use it as a minor action (MP)
- *(Standard)* Ardent Attack [Essence Conduit](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12969), Augment 1 version (PsP)
- *(Standard)* Warlord Attack [Stunning Display](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10984) (MP2)
- *(Standard)* [Platinum Warlord](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=196) Attack [Platinum Blood Smite](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4763), if you hit and is bloodied, one ally can use Second Wind (MP)
- *(Immediate Interrupt)* [Stonecaller](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=416) Utility [Rooted to the Earth](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=8086), when you or ally is subject to forced movement, target can use Second Wind (DP)
- *(Standard)* [Ghallanda Sanctuary Guardian](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=376) Attack [Sanctuary Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7584), for one turn, allies can use it as a minor action (EPG)
- *(Minor)* [Dead God Avatar](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=844) Utility [Summon Divine Presence](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=14069) (Nusemnee version), all allies in the zone can use Second Wind as a minor action (D390)
- *(Second Wind)* Feat [Wind of Sympathy](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3328), one ally in mantle (PsP)
- *(Free, Daily)* [Hero's Armor](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1552), when you spend an Action Point (AV2)
- *(Standard, Daily)* [Standard of Taraskir](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3502), all allies in the zone can use Second Wind as a minor action. (Dungeon 202)

Glossary:

- PHB: [Player's Handbook](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/161671/Players-Handbook-4e)
- PH2: [Player's Handbook 2](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/60481/Players-Handbook-2-4e)
- PH3: [Player's Handbook 3](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/144597/Players-Handbook-3-4e)
- FRPG: [Forgotten Realms Player's Guide](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/57985/Forgotten-Realms-Players-Guide-4e)
- EPG: [Eberron Player's Guide](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/150472/Eberron-Players-Guide-4e)
- AV2: [Adventurer's Vault 2](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/144972/Adventurers-Vault-2-4e)
- MP: [Martial Power](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/58552/Martial-Power-4e)
- MP2: [Martial Power 2](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/143256/Martial-Power-2-4e)
- DP: [Divine Power](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/142370/Divine-Power-4e)
- PrP: [Primal Power](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/142736/Primal-Power-4e)
- PsP: [Psionic Power](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/144596/Psionic-Power-4e)
- HoF: [Heroes of the Feywild](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/121710/Players-Option-Heroes-of-the-Feywild-4e)
- D#: Dragon Magazine, edition #